# Migrate site collection with static pages from SharePoint 2010 to 2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, upgrade

What is the easiest way to migrate? Is there something like saving site as template in SharePoint 2010 and create a new site in SharePoint 2013 with it?

Comment: You can use third party tools available in the markets. They are very efficient to migrate data. Using them, you can directly migrate data from 2010 to 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are going from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013, you can adopt the easy method.

- Backup the content db from 2010 farm ( which contains the Site collections)
- restore it in SharePoint 2013 farm
- Upgrade the content DB
- Test your site collection.

If you dont have too much data then you can try to use the 3rd party tools i.e sharegate. they offer free trail versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no upgrade path between 2010 to 2016. You need to either:

1. Create staging farm with SharePoint 2013 and first upgrade DB with the site to 2013 and then repeat the process to 2016.
2. Recreate site in 2016 and migrate content.